# linear regression output are nonsensical

Tags: python, regression

I have a dataset and am trying to fill in the missing values by utilizing a 2d regression to get the slope of the surrounding curves to approximate the missing value. I am not sure if this is the right approach here, but am open to listen to other ideas. However, here's my example:

```
local_window = pd.DataFrame({102.5: {0.021917: 0.0007808776581961896,
                                 0.030136: 0.0009108521507099643,
                                 0.035616: 0.001109650616093018,
                                 0.041095: 0.0013238862647034224,
                                 0.060273: 0.0018552410055933753},
                         105.0: {0.021917: 0.0008955896980595855,
                                 0.030136: 0.001003244315807649,
                                 0.035616: 0.0011852612740301449,
                                 0.041095: 0.0013952857530607904,
                                 0.060273: 0.0018525880756980716},
                         107.5: {0.021917: np.nan,
                                 0.030136: 0.0012354997955153118,
                                 0.035616: 0.00140044893559622,
                                 0.041095: 0.0015902024099268574,
                                 0.060273: 0.001973254493672934}})
```

```
def predict_nan_local(local_window):
    if not local_window.isnull().values.any():
        return local_window
    
    # Extract x and y values for the local window
    X_local = local_window.columns.values.copy()
    y_local = local_window.index.values.copy()

    # Create a meshgrid of x and y values
    X_local, y_local = np.meshgrid(X_local, y_local)

    # Flatten x and y for fitting the model
    X_local_flat = X_local.flatten()
    y_local_flat = y_local.flatten()
    values_local_flat = local_window.values.flatten()
    
    # Find indices of non-NaN values
    non_nan_indices = ~np.isnan(values_local_flat)

    # Filter out NaN values
    X_local_flat_filtered = X_local_flat[non_nan_indices]
    y_local_flat_filtered = y_local_flat[non_nan_indices]
    values_local_flat_filtered = values_local_flat[non_nan_indices]

    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(np.column_stack((X_local_flat_filtered, y_local_flat_filtered)), values_local_flat_filtered)
    
    nan_indices = np.argwhere(np.isnan(local_window.values))
    X_nan = local_window.columns.values[nan_indices[:, 1]]
    y_nan = local_window.index.values[nan_indices[:, 0]]
    
    # Predict missing value
    predicted_values = regressor.predict(np.column_stack((X_nan, y_nan)))

    local_window.iloc[nan_indices[:, 0], nan_indices[:, 1]] = predicted_values

    return local_window
```

[image]

The output - as you can see - doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made some modifications to your predict function:

```
def predict_nan_local(local_window, degree=2):
    # Only proceed if there are NaNs to fill
    if not local_window.isnull().values.any():
        return local_window
    
    # Create a meshgrid of x and y values
    x = local_window.columns.values
    y = local_window.index.values
    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    
    # Flatten the grid for fitting
    X_flat = X.ravel()
    Y_flat = Y.ravel()
    Z_flat = local_window.values.ravel()
    
    # Filter out NaN values
    valid_mask = ~np.isnan(Z_flat)
    X_valid = X_flat[valid_mask]
    Y_valid = Y_flat[valid_mask]
    Z_valid = Z_flat[valid_mask]
    
    # Create polynomial features
    poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
    XY_poly = poly.fit_transform(np.column_stack((X_valid, Y_valid)))
    
    # Fit the model
    regressor = LinearRegression()
    regressor.fit(XY_poly, Z_valid)
    
    # Predict missing values
    XY_all_poly = poly.transform(np.column_stack((X_flat, Y_flat)))
    Z_pred_flat = regressor.predict(XY_all_poly)
    
    # Fill in the missing values
    Z_flat[~valid_mask] = Z_pred_flat[~valid_mask]
    filled_local_window = pd.DataFrame(Z_flat.reshape(local_window.shape), index=y, columns=x)
    
    return filled_local_window
```

Running this on your data:

```
predict_nan_local(local_window)

               102.5       105.0       107.5
0.021917    0.000781    0.000896    0.001089
0.030136    0.000911    0.001003    0.001235
0.035616    0.001110    0.001185    0.001400
0.041095    0.001324    0.001395    0.001590
0.060273    0.001855    0.001853    0.001973
```

So we have imputed 0.001089 for the missing value. Plotting this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Assuming local_window is your DataFrame with the same structure as in your example
local_window = pd.DataFrame({
    102.5: {0.021917: 0.0007808776581961896,
            0.030136: 0.0009108521507099643,
            0.035616: 0.001109650616093018,
            0.041095: 0.0013238862647034224,
            0.060273: 0.0018552410055933753},
    105.0: {0.021917: 0.0008955896980595855,
            0.030136: 0.001003244315807649,
            0.035616: 0.0011852612740301449,
            0.041095: 0.0013952857530607904,
            0.060273: 0.0018525880756980716},
    107.5: {0.021917: 0.001089,
            0.030136: 0.0012354997955153118,
            0.035616: 0.00140044893559622,
            0.041095: 0.0015902024099268574,
            0.060273: 0.001973254493672934}
})

# Transpose the DataFrame to plot each x-value (102.5, 105.0, 107.5) as a separate line
local_window_transposed = local_window.T

# Create the plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5))

# Plot each column as a separate line
for column in local_window_transposed.columns:
    plt.plot(local_window_transposed.index, local_window_transposed[column], marker='o', label=f'y={column}')

# Find missing data point(s)
for col in local_window_transposed.columns:
    missing_data = local_window_transposed[col].isnull()
    if missing_data.any():
        missing_x = local_window_transposed.index[missing_data]
        for mx in missing_x:
            plt.scatter(mx, local_window[col][mx], s=100, facecolors='none', edgecolors='r')

# Add titles and labels
plt.title('Chart Title')
plt.xlabel('X-axis Label')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis Label')
plt.legend(title='Legend Title')

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is this closer to what you expected ?